# usort php array/object multidimensional

Tags: php, usort

I'm having trouble making php `usort` work.

I fetch this from DB:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 10 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-14 15:09:33 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-14 15:09:33 [post_content] => asdad [post_title] => geo [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => geo [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 10:54:14 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:54:14 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=10 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-19 00:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-09-19 23:59:59 [filter] => raw ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 39 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-16 11:01:32 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-16 11:01:32 [post_content] =>
Sorry, this entry is only available in English and Russian.
[post_title] => 19 [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => 39 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 11:01:49 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 11:01:49 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=39 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-19 08:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-09-19 17:00:00 [filter] => raw ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 37 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-16 10:55:47 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:55:47 [post_content] => asd [post_title] => event [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => event [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 10:55:47 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:55:47 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=37 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 1 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-21 08:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-09-21 17:00:00 [filter] => raw ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 38 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content] => asdsa [post_title] => sada [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => sada [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=38 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-27 08:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-09-30 17:00:00 [filter] => raw ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 38 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content] => asdsa [post_title] => sada [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => sada [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=38 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-28 08:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-10-01 17:00:00 [filter] => raw ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 38 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content] => asdsa [post_title] => sada [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => sada [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=38 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-29 08:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-10-02 17:00:00 [filter] => raw ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 38 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content] => asdsa [post_title] => sada [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => sada [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-09-16 10:57:01 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://localhost/gold/?post_type=tribe_events&p=38 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => tribe_events [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [EventStartDate] => 2012-09-30 08:00:00 [EventEndDate] => 2012-10-03 17:00:00 [filter] => raw ) )
```

I'd like to order this using usort and comment_count object. I've tried this (but it is obviously wrong):

```
function sortByComments($a, $b) {
    return ($a[0]->comment_count) - ($b[0]->comment_count);
}

$sorted_by_comments_array = usort($all_events, 'sortByComments');
```

Error:  `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: You can probably do this in your sql statement, can you provide that as well?

Comment: @KorvinSzanto will not this be faster than sql statement?

Comment: no, you're already doing running the sql statement, sorting a massive uncompressed array is not faster when the sql is already sorting it while compressed.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto I'm using wordpress wp_quer function, so not running sql query directly. Even in this case is it better to run sql query directly rather than use wp hook? BTW ty for answering my questions, I'm really interested in learning efficient ways.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how wordpress handles it, but if the data's all there, it would be much more efficient to manually join the tables and sort by the amount of comments, by many orders of magnitude.

Comment: Have a look at the **orderby** in the [documentation for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). @KorvinSzanto is correct about it being faster doing this in the query and not sorting the output in PHP.

Comment: @nerdklers cannot use orderby as this is wp calendar query, it has its own variables, I didn't want to explain in detail that's why I said wp_quer but its not and it doesn't accept orderby parameter. I got that mysql will be faster. But I can't really do it, cause plugin uses meta_fields in db to create complex web of data. Right now simplest solution is php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it a little hard to read your array's structure, but I think I'm right in saying that the elements of the array are the objects you want to sort. This means that `$a` and `$b` will themselves be the objects you need to sort.

This therefore means that you don't need to access them as `$a[0]->comment_count` but simply as `$a->comment_count`:

```
function sortByComments($a, $b) {
    return $a->comment_count - $b->comment_count;
}
```

(Note that the brackets are also unnecessary.)

Comment: It worked! But how would I reverse the order? now it orders 0 1, I'd like it to order 1, 0 comment_count.

Comment: `return $b->comment_count - $a->comment_count;` will reverse the order.

Comment: Can I also do this? return $a->comment_count < $b->comment_count;

Comment: @SandroDzneladze No, because it wants a ternary, rather than a binary: "is `$a` lower than `$b`, higher, or the same?"